# Why the type of (pure [] 3) is "[a]"?

Tags: haskell

When I checked on ghci, I found this behavior;

```
Prelude> :t pure []
pure [] :: Applicative f => f [a]

Prelude> :t pure [] 3
pure [] 3 :: [a]
Prelude> pure [] 3
[]
```

I am not sure why it is like this, why `pure [] 3` is type of `[a]`?
What happens in the last expression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer**: It uses `(->) b` as `f` here.

The type of `pure []` is `pure [] :: Applicative f => f [a]` as you first derived. Now you are calling that as a function. So that means that Haskell infers that `f ~ Num b => (->) b` with `b` the type of the `3`. We are lucky here, since `(->) b` is indeed an instance of [`Applicative`, it is defined as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-822):

> ```
> instance Applicative ((->) a) where
>     pure = const
>     (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
>     liftA2 q f g x = q (f x) (g x)
> ```

So here the `pure` is interpreted as [**`const :: a -> b -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:const). We thus have written:

```
   pure [] 3
-> const [] 3
-> (\_ -> []) 3
-> []
```

`const` thus ignores the `3` here, and thus the return type is a `[]` where the list can contain items of any type.

Comment: Good answer. I think OP’s question implies they were expecting the result `[3] :: Num a => [a]`. So for their sake, some ways of using `pure` / `[]` / `3` to obtain that result include: `pure 3 :: Num a => [a]`; `pure @[] 3` (with `TypeApplications`); `(pure :: Num a => a -> [a]) 3`; and of course, using `pure 3` in any context where the list type would be inferred.